# form action not navigating in include page

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a page called`emp.php` in which i have the following code

```
 <form action="emp-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          include("conn.php");                 

 $sud=$_SESSION['login_user'];

            $sqlc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp where un='".$sud."' ");

            $countc=mysql_num_rows($sqlc);
            if($countc<99)
            {

         include("inc-profile.php");
            }
            else
            {
            echo "SORRY !!!!you have posted more than 100 jobs"; 

            } 

</form>
```

now this is working properly and navigates to `inc-profile` page according to condition

in `inc-profile.php` page I have

```
<form action="include-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

//some codes

 </form>
```

But form action is not nvigating to`include-action.php` page but navigating `emp-action.php`page ..What might be the error
PLZ NOT I HAVE REMOVED `.PHP` WITH HELP OF `.HTACCES`

Comment: Well, might be obvious, but you are missing `session_start()` before `$_SESSION`.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You may also be **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: It seems you are nesting forms. Avoid that, this is against HTML standard specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one form inside another form.

This is forbidden by the HTML specification and causes undesirable results.

Don't nest forms.

Comment: what should i do to  navigate form that is present inside the include page?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you want two forms, then separate them. Close one before starting another.

Comment: ,ya The thing  is that I have an include page right.How can I navigate contents in include page ie.`inc-profile.php` to `include-action` page without form action?

Comment: Move the include to after `</form>` or move `</form>` to before the include.

Comment: ,moving `</form>`before include worked fine..THANK YOU so much

Answer (score 0):

as per your code you have 2 forms like this

```
<form action="emp-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <form action="include-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      </form>
</form>
```

so when you submit the the first Form action will be initiated. please do like below

```
<form action="emp-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


</form>
  include("conn.php");                 

 $sud=$_SESSION['login_user'];

            $sqlc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp where un='".$sud."' ");

            $countc=mysql_num_rows($sqlc);
            if($countc<99)
            {

         include("inc-profile.php");
            }
            else
            {
            echo "SORRY !!!!you have posted more than 100 jobs"; 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one problems in your code.
As D.Kasipovic said you have to use session_start().

But you have also to differentiate html from php for
example with php tag `<?php ?>`

like this

```
 <form action="emp-action" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
       include("conn.php");                 

        $sud=$_SESSION['login_user'];

        $sqlc=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp where un='".$sud."' ");

        $countc=mysql_num_rows($sqlc);
        if($countc<99)
        {

     include("inc-profile.php");
        }
        else
        {
        echo "SORRY !!!!you have posted more than 100 jobs"; 

        } ?>
</form>
```